# Searching the next line

Tags: python, regex, newline

I need to write a python regex that will match a word that is next to the matched word. But the next word can be in next line or can be same line.

Eg:

```
"""
Running /health_checks/system_checks1     [ FAIL ] 
Running /health_checks/system_checks2       [ PASS ] 
Running /health_checks/system_checks3           
                                         [ PASS ] 
"""
```

After system_checks3 there is new line and then the result of the check.

I want the result like :

```
system_checks2 PASS
system_checks3 PASS
```

and so on

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question. No problem is stated in the post.

Comment: I want the result like : system_checks2 PASS,  system_checks3 PASS and so on

Comment: I don't think regex is a good tool for this. Best would be to make the output more structured in the first place. If that is impossible, you might still get some results by split(). For example, it seems like a good idea to just remove the linebreaks, make that one long string, and call split("running") on it. then you can look for the substring within [] easily

Comment: If we split by "Running", then the result of the check will come in the next line than that of the check name(system_checks3).

Comment: You're right. That can be fixed by first removing the linebreaks, so that everything is just one long string. I've posted an answer which might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to use a different output format in the first place.
Using regex to parse output is rarely a good idea, the code just breaks too easily: At some point the output will be changed, your program will break, and reading regex again after a month is a headache.

Assuming you can't change the output format, then I would still recommend not to use regexes. You might want to look into the python function `split()`, here is a version using it:

```
string="""
Running /health_checks/system_checks1     [ FAIL ] 
Running /health_checks/system_checks2       [ PASS ] 
Running /health_checks/system_checks3           
                                         [ PASS ] 
"""

# remove newlines
string = string.replace("\n", "")

# split into individual jobs
jobs=string.split("Running")

# remove empty strings
jobs=[job for job in jobs if job!=""]

# take only the part with the result
results=[]
for job in jobs:
    # separate in the process name and the result
    # assuming the result is always wrapped in []
    # then [ can be used as a delimiter
    splitted=job.split("[")

    # splitted contains the job name and the result
    result=splitted[1]

    # remove the trailing ]
    result=result.replace("]","")

    # remove whitespace
    result=result.strip()

    results.append(result)
```

The `results` array now contains:

> ['FAIL', 'PASS', 'PASS']

Answer (score 0):

While a regex is sometimes not the best choice for text processing, there's nothing wrong with it in this case.

> But the next word can be in next line or can be same line.

No problem, `\s` matches any whitespace character, including `\n`.

```
string="""
Running /health_checks/system_checks1     [ FAIL ] 
Running /health_checks/system_checks2       [ PASS ] 
Running /health_checks/system_checks3           
                                         [ PASS ] 
"""
import re
result = re.findall("(\w+)\s*\[ (PASS) ]", string)
for tuple in result: print ' '.join(tuple)
```